# how to use variable inside <xml-module:xpath-extract> mule 4

Tags: xpath, mule, dataweave, mule4

I have a variable set value as "Active." Based on the value of a variable, I want to select a node in the payload.

If I give values directly in xpath, it's work.

When I'm trying to use variables inside an xpath, like **@Status = vars.xstatus**. It returns a null value [].

Mule 4 flow:

```
<flow name="var_xpath_testFlow" doc:id="406270fb-17e7-48e9-a33a-f7a0197f8e05" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="662f2277-859f-4516-974b-de7cceeb5b40" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/vartest"/>
        <set-variable value="Active" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="12370458-bb32-4709-b509-acc1e5f50b94" variableName="xstatus"/>
        <xml-module:xpath-extract doc:id="6027ebad-f81d-4df1-8234-3d8dab04b129" config-ref="XML_Config" xpath="/DTOApplication/DTOLocation[@Status=vars.xstatus ]" target="xvalue"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="f495b0bf-f8cb-43be-b4d9-d069758e4028" message="#[vars.xvalue]"/>
</flow>
```

XPATH expression:

```
/DTOApplication/DTOLocation[@Status='Active']
```

XML payload: https://github.com/Manikandan99/rate-dtostep/blob/master/request.xml

how to use variables in XPath Mule 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a literal string use a Mule 4 expression.

Something like:

```js
xpath="#[&quot;/DTOApplication/DTOLocation[@Status='&quot; ++ vars.xstatus ++ &quot;']&quot;]"/>
```

Comment: what is use of &quot; in code?

Comment: Since the expression is inside the value of an XML attribute, which uses double quotes as a delimiter, if you use double quotes inside the expression they to be escaped, according to XML escaping conventions. Note that the UI will do that for you if you use the graphical view. If you use the XML view you need to do it yourself.

Comment: your code work. Only if we include "& qot" will it work.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your code, use below code that is having corrections for the xpath expression

```
<flow name="var_xpath_testFlow" doc:id="7490a882-4473-461d-846b-b6a7b65a8eca" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="4767ed08-42cb-467c-80c2-4b739c68724e" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/vartest"/>
        <set-variable value="Active" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="62eaffcf-ea2e-4f05-8ad8-d840bbebe9e4" variableName="xstatus"/>
        <xml-module:xpath-extract doc:id="15124867-b70c-4656-8eb9-d99d4e500a0e" config-ref="XML_Config" xpath='#["/DTOApplication/DTOLocation[@Status=" ++ vars.xstatus ++ "]"]' target="xvalue"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="340b9b89-18f8-4584-b6cb-7ab9d6d8efed" message="#[vars.xvalue]"/>
</flow>
```

Below is the screenshot that is showing how and where I did a correction
[image]

In the above screenshot as I Mentioned that click on "fx", if you add the expression without clicking on it and run your code, you will get an error as below

```
"Could not compile xpath expression "/DTOApplication/DTOLocation[@Status=" ++ vars.xstatus ++ "]""
```

In Mule 3, you must learn both the Mule Expression Language (MEL) and DataWeave. but now in Mule-4 DataWeave is the default expression language, if you click on "fx" it means you are entering DataWeave Expression Language

After this correction, I am getting correct output as in the below snippet
[image]

below is the complete xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule
    xmlns:xml-module="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml-module"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:x12="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/x12"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/x12 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/x12/current/mule-x12.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml-module http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml-module/current/mule-xml-module.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config"
        doc:name="HTTP Listener config"
        doc:id="5fe97da4-b1a9-4a9b-9a23-c4c42249fb2b">
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0"
            port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <xml-module:config name="XML_Config"
        doc:name="XML Config" doc:id="6c8afa4c-6fec-4791-94a3-b4f8f63442e7" />

    <flow name="var_xpath_testFlow"
        doc:id="7490a882-4473-461d-846b-b6a7b65a8eca">
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener"
            doc:id="4767ed08-42cb-467c-80c2-4b739c68724e"
            config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/vartest" />
        <set-variable value="Active" doc:name="Set Variable"
            doc:id="62eaffcf-ea2e-4f05-8ad8-d840bbebe9e4" variableName="xstatus" />
        <xml-module:xpath-extract
            doc:id="15124867-b70c-4656-8eb9-d99d4e500a0e" config-ref="XML_Config"
            xpath='#["/DTOApplication/DTOLocation[@Status=" ++ vars.xstatus ++ "]"]'
            target="xvalue" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"
            doc:id="340b9b89-18f8-4584-b6cb-7ab9d6d8efed"
            message="#[vars.xvalue]" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Note: I am using Anypoint Studio version 7.11.1 ad Mule runtime version -4.4.0 (but I tried with runtime 4.3.0 and its working fine)

Comment: I tried your code but it returns a null array like []

Comment: have you followed attached screenshots? and gave same xml in input?

Comment: yeah! I followed all those steps you mentioned. but it's not work. I appreciate it...

Comment: let me add the working xml file for you in my answer