# can't extract value from xpath-extract using mule variables

Tags: xpath, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a set **LocationProperties** variable as its **Location-465697646-800339871** value. Based on the value of a variable, I want to select a node in the payload.

Mule 3:

```
xpath3('//DTOLocation[@id=\'' + flowVars.LocationProperties.LocationRef + '\'][1]/DTOLocationDetail[@DetailTypeCd=\'CommercialPropertyLocationDetail\'][1]/@ProtectionClassCd',flowVars.domPayload)
xpath3('//DTOLocation[@id=' + flowVars.LocationProperties.LocationRef + '][1]/@LocationCounterNumber',flowVars.domPayload)
```

Mule 4 flow:

```
<flow name="var_xpath_testFlow" doc:id="406270fb-17e7-48e9-a33a-f7a0197f8e05" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="662f2277-859f-4516-974b-de7cceeb5b40" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/vartest"/>
        <set-variable value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set domPayload" doc:id="2495ac98-b976-41e0-9dcf-398574e54ffa" variableName="domPayload"/>
        <set-variable value="Location-465697646-800339871" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="12370458-bb32-4709-b509-acc1e5f50b94" variableName="LocationProperties"/>
        <xml-module:xpath-extract xpath="#[&quot;/DTOApplication/DTOLocation[@id='&quot; ++ vars.LocationProperties ++ &quot;'][1]&quot;/DTOLocationDetail[@DetailTypeCd='CommercialPropertyLocationDetail'][1]/@ProtectionClassCd]" target="xvalue1" config-ref="XML_Config"/>
        <xml-module:xpath-extract xpath="#[&quot;/DTOApplication/DTOLocation[@id='&quot; ++ vars.LocationProperties ++ &quot;'][1]&quot;/@LocationCounterNumber]" config-ref="XML_Config" target="xvalue2"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="f495b0bf-f8cb-43be-b4d9-d069758e4028" message="#[vars.xvalue]"/>
    </flow>
```

Input payload: https://github.com/Manikandan99/rate-dtostep/blob/master/request.xml

Expected output is the variable :

**xvalue1 returns 3,**

**xvalue2 returns 1.**

If I give values directly in xpath, it's work.

When I'm trying to use variables inside an xpath,it throws error like : https://github.com/Manikandan99/rate-dtostep/blob/master/xapth_error.txt

How to extract value using variables in XPath Mule 4?

Comment: please stop using links to share information that should be inside your questions as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. See section "Help others reproduce the problem" for the detailed explanation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70985535/how-to-use-variable-inside-xml-modulexpath-extract-mule-4  is it not same type of question,asked by you?

Comment: i request you to to do analysis of error by yourself also as you already asked same type of question.only syntax analysis required for this

Comment: Aled, while posting a question, stackoverflow doesn't allows to post more code in the question. Therefore, I used git links in the question.

Comment: Anurag, I'm super confused with @quot; That's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you have not added double code correctly in the expression of XPath

I have done some corrections as below

```
    <flow name="var_xpath_testFlow" doc:id="406270fb-17e7-48e9-a33a-f7a0197f8e05" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="662f2277-859f-4516-974b-de7cceeb5b40" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/vartest"/>
        <set-variable value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set domPayload" doc:id="2495ac98-b976-41e0-9dcf-398574e54ffa" variableName="domPayload"/>
        <set-variable value="Location-465697646-800339871" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="12370458-bb32-4709-b509-acc1e5f50b94" variableName="LocationProperties"/>
        <xml-module:xpath-extract doc:name="Xpath extract" doc:id="4a8ce1ed-3c1c-48f7-95dd-664654c6a66b" xpath="#[&quot;/DTOApplication/DTOLocation[@id='&quot; ++ vars.LocationProperties ++ &quot;'][1]/DTOLocationDetail[@DetailTypeCd='CommercialPropertyLocationDetail'][1]/@ProtectionClassCd&quot;]"/>
        <xml-module:xpath-extract doc:name="Xpath extract" doc:id="6287299e-aae5-411b-b6d5-936e6c6be5fb" xpath="#[&quot;/DTOApplication/DTOLocation[@id='&quot; ++ vars.LocationProperties ++ &quot;'][1]/@LocationCounterNumber&quot;]"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="f495b0bf-f8cb-43be-b4d9-d069758e4028" message="#[vars.xvalue]"/>
    </flow>
```

With this, your error will get resolved, which is mentioned in your question. Also, I am not sure why are you setting the payload initially in a variable called domPayload, because you are not using it. Please look into that

as per our discussion in comments, for your expected output use below dataweave code just after second Xpath extractor

```
%dw 2.0 
output application/json 
--- 
(vars.xvalue1 default [] ++ vars.xvalue2 default []) joinBy ","
```

the o/p will be:- "3,1"

Comment: Anurag sharma , You did great work. but it returns [3],[1]. how to remove this square brackets?

Comment: what is expected o/p?

Comment: it's just 3 and 1.

Comment: first, are you trying using domPayload variable in both xpath or at least in second xpath extractor? becasue you are setting and not using it. and becasue of that your payload is getting overridden by one another.Also expected output is  "3 and 1" like this? if yes then you need to save both payload into a varibale (that is coming from xpath extractor, just after xpath extractors) and then you can do anything with that

Comment: Actually, I tried just by copy paste your flow .but when I try to log this value it's shows [3] and [1] . I'm not using that Dom payload in my flow; I just use it to store the input request.

Comment: no problem, try to set a variable (ater each Xpath extract) with the o/p payload of Xpath extract and at the end use both of them to transform your o/p. or lt me know exact o/p specified correctly

Comment: Anurag, I used the target variable instead of using a set variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241824/discussion-between-anurag-sharma-and-codey-08).

Comment: I think You left the chat room, as per our discussion in comments i have added the code for expected output

Comment: I used reduce($$+$) in target value like ( targetValue="#[payload reduce ($$+$)]" ). it's work. Thanks Anurag : )